# UTF-8 Encoding in console output - Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, utf-8, sh

I already checked so many post related to that subject in stack overflow,
but nothing helped.

So the issue is that i would like to see some polish chars on my console output,
but instead of that chars i see question marks

`echo '???'`

So i have jenkins version 2.323.
I already added following params in global vars for jenkins:

- JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
- LANG=UTF-8

also added those params to all nodes as a env variables

Is anyone able to support in that case ?

EDIT:

I am executing following commands in my shell execution step:

`echo "ąęĆ"`

And after when i run build i see:

```
[sth] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2984595068288236962.sh
+ echo ???
???
Finished: SUCCESS
```

EDIT:

I also read that maybe i should add encoding to sh, so i did like that:

```
+ /bin/sh encoding: UTF-8 script: echo "???"
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open encoding:
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

But seems like syntax is bad. Forgive me but im not so experienced in such a things.

EDIT:
When im executing locale charmap i can see

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

seems like ansi still is used.

Thanks,
J

Comment: First of all, make sure to open & save the file in **UTF-8** encoding. Secondly, try setting this `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: `locale -a` will show installed locales. `UTF-8` is not one of them. The locale has no bearing on this, though. It's all about the encoding of the file and the encoding expected by the terminal. Also, there could be font issues.